# Javascript Validation Help - Input must equal value of Blue

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

My validation works for empty fields. However, I'd like to know how I can check the value of an input field and return false if not correct.

The User MUST input the word "Blue" to complete the form.

**Input**

```
<input type="text" id="formcheck" class="contact" maxlength="255" />
```

**Current Validation Check**

> if (f. formcheck.value != 'Blue')  {   alert('Please enter the
>   correct word.')   f. formcheck.focus()   return false;  }

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: Can you update your question and make what you're trying to do clearer. Also your missing two `;`.

Comment: `id` and `name` attributes are not the same, especially in forms. It should be `document.getElementById('formcheck').value `. Or give the `input` a name, like `name="blue"`, and then you can access it by the form name method.

Answer (score 0):

Example code, i used jquery only for click binding:

```
<input type="text" id="formcheck" class="contact" maxlength="255" value="Blue"/>
<input type="button" id="clickB" value="click me">
```

​

```
$("#clickB").click(function(){
   if (document.getElementById('formcheck').value != 'Blue') {
       alert('Please enter the correct word.');
       document.getElementById('formcheck').focus();
       return false;
   }
})
```

​
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6yYp/)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error, you forget the adding `;` end of each statement.

```
if (f.formcheck.value != 'Blue') {
    alert('Please enter the correct word.')
    f.formcheck.focus()
    return false
}
```

---

or use in your way but add `;`

```
if (f.formcheck.value != 'Blue') { alert('Please enter the correct word.');  f.formcheck.focus();  return false; }
```